# Found an old question with bad links in the answers. What do I do?

Tags: support

The accepted answer has a bad link as well.

I can't answer the question myself as I'm actually looking for the answer.

[What is the best Authentication and Authorization library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252079/what-is-the-best-authentication-and-authorization-library-for-codeigniter)

UPDATE: I no longer need to find the answer to my question, but the question above should be removed...?

Comment: I did find a better question with good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311725/codeigniter-3-x-authentication-library

Comment: Could you find more dupes, pls?

Answer (score 1):

As per your update, yes, the question isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's a recommendation question. Also, as [you pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305980/found-an-old-question-with-bad-links-in-the-answers-what-do-i-do#comment994589_305980), you found a better answer to your own question in another question.

The former question (in your question body) should definitely be closed. I'd say it isn't quite a duplicate of the latter question, since they involve different versions of the same library, but it's definitely off-topic, and should be closed as such at a minimum. The latter question (in your comment) is borderline on-topic, as (despite the first sentence) it shows research effort to determine a good library, and asks a few other questions, but based on the answers it is probably opinion-based and possibly also too broad because it asks multiple questions. I'd recommend casting a recommend closure flag on it, so it can be reviewed.

As far as deleting the latter question: are the other answers still useful? Is the question overall still useful to other readers? Or are any of them out of date because of broken links or incompatibility with the latest library? Consider these, and downvote the question and/or any answers if they are not useful. If the whole question isn't useful to others because all of the answers aren't useful, I think a moderator flag is in order.

Comment: So should I just flag it?

Comment: @ssaltman Flag what as what?

Comment: Sorry, flag the original question? Or flag the original answer?

Comment: @ssaltman Edited my comment. Flag what post as what?

Comment: That's my question - what do I do this situation when I find a question that has no valid answers.

Comment: @ssaltman So all of the answers aren't useful? Flag the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

First check the wayback machine (web archive) to see if it has an archive of the website.

Or you can flag the answer as a mod flag and explain that it should be removed (answer or question as needed)